# Is there a way to find and interact with specific processes in Windows using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to find the process responsible for managing calls in Teams.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Tub.png
As shown in the printscreen, there are 9 processes inside Teams looking through the Task Manager.
I've seen that it is possible to identify the process responsible for calls looking at the CPU and GPU usage when you call someone.
I wanted to identify this process in a more reliable way using System.Diagnostics, with IDs or something, but I found nothing in the code that could help me with that, as the process ID changes by the time I kill the process.

This is my code:

```
        List<object> Lista;
        Lista = new List<object>();
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (var process in processes)
        
            if (process.ProcessName.ToUpper().Contains("TEAMS"))
            {
                Lista.Add(process.Id);
            }
        }
        var log = Lista;
```

(It's my first post here, I would appreciate some tips)

Comment: It is entirely up to Teams how it arranges responsibilities between its different forks. Any way you could find to identify the app would be unreliable, and subject to change with any version change. It may be possible to distinguish these applications by looking at their command lines -- there is, however, no built-in .NET or Win32 API for retrieving that, and it requires either futzing around in internals with `ReadProcessMemory` or using WMI (which exposes it in the `Win32_Process` class).

Comment: There is no "reliable" way using System.Diagnostics. Checking CPU usage is extremely unreliable because you don't know for sure that the process utilizing the CPU the most is the one making calls. You also can't tell when the user is making a call without hooking into the program or asking for user input. This is not as trivial as a task as you think it is. The best solution would be to reverse engineer Teams and inject your own code into it that can communicate with your program and explicitly tell it when a call starts.

Comment: Thank you much for the reply. So, if it isn't possible to know exactly which process does it, is there a way to at least identify whenever a call is started?